# Why Google Play Store is showing two devices when I try to download and open an app?

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

[Play Store showing multiple devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP0Mk.jpg)

I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Use Google Play App instead of Web